# parseConten($content) doesn't work in php script

Tags: php, regex, replace

just wondering why this code isn't working:

```
    protected function parseContent($content) {
    $linkTable = array (
        'user\.php\?id=' => 'User_link'
        );
    foreach ($linkTable as $class => $code) {
    $content = preg_replace('/\<a href="https?:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/[\w\s-]+\b'.$class.'\<\/a\>/', $code, $content);
    }
    return trim($content); }
```

It should replace something like this

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/max.mustermann?directed_target_id=0" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1234567&extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A0%7D">Max Mustermann</a>
```

into this

> User_link

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use preg_quote and you won't need to escape every character in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You need more slashes!

```
$linkTable = array (
        'user\\.php\\?id=' => 'User_link'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, now no more error message, but command still doesnt't do what I want it to do. Url output stays the same.